# ORM 'or_where' use

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-orm

I'd like my ORM factory to return records where x = 1 and y is either equal to 1 or 2. I've tried a few variations with and_where, but it returns loads more than records than it should. The ORM is then stored in a php variable. Here's my current code

```
$tests = ORM::factory('Test')
    ->where('x', '=', 1)
    ->or_where('y', '=', 1)
    ->or_where('y', '=', 2)
    ->find_all();
```

Comment: Cause it's returning something like `SELECT * FROM test WHERE x=1 OR y=1 OR y=2;` so it's ignoring first statement (`x=1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the `OR` statements via [`and_where_open()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM#and_where_open)/[`and_where_close()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM#and_where_close) like so (untested)

```
$test = ORM::factory('Test')
    ->where('x', '=', 1)     // 1
    ->and_where_open()       // 2
    ->where('y', '=', 1)     // 3
    ->or_where('y', '=', 2)  // 4
    ->and_where_close()
    ->find_all();
```

This should create a query like

```
SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE x = 1   AND (  y=1   OR y=2  )
                        ^^^^^   ^^^^^  ^^^   ^^^^^^
                          1       2     3      4
```